# Too "big" Arrays. Do I need a DataBase? Or are there other options?

Tags: c#, .net, database, arrays, out-of-memory

I recently encountered an OutOfMemory error in a program due to (I guess) an excessive use of arrays and <del>double</del> multidimensional arrays (one which is around 5000x60 elements). So I'm searching for an alternative to storing the information.

Are databases the only alternative? Or is there any other way to the store the information from the arrays so I can free up memory? I also read about the possibility of manually allocating memory (or splitting it up in chunks? I don't recall what exactly it was) but that's not an option I guess because all the arrays and objects will eventually grow even more in size so sooner or later I'd probably even reach (in theory) the limits of my physical ram. Although I might just be wrong here.

I'm not asking for huge code examples, links to good tutorials or reads (books would be ok too although I should be able to order them in Germany without billions of dollars shipping costs ;-)) would be perfect.

Also: No, I never did anything with databases but I'm willing to learn anything.

Thanks in advance for any help.

edit: fixed "double array" to "multidimensional array".

edit2: I thought there might be an "universal" solution to a problem with huge arrays but you prooved me wrong. Because it's hard to find an alternative if people don't know what I'm doing here's a quick overview of what I'm doing (it's mostly for statistical purposes):

- Read data from a CSV file, each line resembles a custom object MyClass1 containing around 60 objects MyClass2.
- Iterate through all the instances of MyClass1, adding or editing properties of each of the MyClass2 objects, depending on various conditions.

If more information is needed, I'll surely post it. The reason I don't post code is because I basically wouldn't know which lines from around 4000 to pick out. I'm not trying to hold any information back because I'm coding something super secret, I simply don't know what else might be useful.

edit3: Question: "could you process each line at a time, or do you need the context of the whole file first?"

- I do need the context of the whole file. So for example MyClass1[4000][0] depends on Data from MyClass1[0][0], MyClass1[1][0] etc. More information: Reading the CSV file and creating the "empty" objects works fine. The error gets thrown later on when I iterate through all the MyClass1 objects.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Okay, now it's slightly clearer what you're doing... but a multidimensional array of size 5000 x 60 is still only 300,000 elements. What is each element? Do you think you *actually* need more data in memory at a time than your machine can handle?

It's not really clear what you're doing - do you definitely need *all* the information in memory at once? Perhaps the problem is that you're preventing the arrays from being garbage collected when you're dne with them?

Without knowing what sort of processing you're doing, it's hard to know whether a database is appropriate, but arrays are about as efficient as you're likely to get if you actually need a value for every element. If you could manage with a sparse array, that would be a different matter of course.

Comment: > use of arrays and double arrays (one which is around 5000x60 elements)
I think he means _Two Dimensional_ array but not array of `double`.

Comment: @xandy: you're right, I fixed it in the entry post.
@Jon Skeet: I don't really need ALL the information in memory at once, definitely not. some if it could be accessed "on demand". But I'm clueless about where to store the information? I don't think writing/read text files would really be "efficient"? See, my knowledge about MemoryManagement is just as non-existant as my knowledge about databases ;-)

Comment: @Germony, strictly speaking, even you put those data to text files can be described as `database`. You definitely need db to handle your stuff, as long as they are on demand. If your objects are simple in structure, go for traditional Relational-DB; if your object is complex (like A contains B contains C), you may look at XML-DBs or Document DBs, they act closer to object representation.

Comment: @xandy: the type of database the OP should use should be determined not by the structure of the data, but by the access pattern.  Relational databases are unlikely to perform well in an access pattern that favors an array - non-relational key/value stores like BDB are probably a better place to start.

Comment: @Gernony: Without giving us any hint about what you're doing, it's very hard to give you any advice to be honest.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Added more information to the entry post, didn't know there might be different ways to go, really depending on what I'm doing. Sorry. @xandy: My objects are more complex indeed, I'll definitely take a look at XML-DBs or Document DBs. Even if those might not be the solution here, it sure might be good to know about it. @NickBastin: what's a BDB?

Comment: @Gernony: Okay, so first question: could you process each line at a time, or do you need the context of the whole file first?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I do need the context of the whole file. So for example MyClass1[4000][0] depends on Data from MyClass1[0][0], MyClass1[1][0] etc. More information: Reading the CSV file and creating the "empty" objects works fine. The error gets thrown later on when I iterate through all the MyClass1 objects. I'll add my answers to your question to the entry post too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when used large structures memory never cleans and when you pass such array to method, all memory are copied, so OutOfMemoryException it's a possible result of such large arrays, read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/uncontrolled_loh_size.aspx) to solve the problem